# Nginx can't find static files

Tags: django, nginx, django-staticfiles

o know that it is oftenn question.
I have
2 servers with the same nginx config

```
location /static/ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }
```

real dicrectory for static is `/var/www/html/static`

One server see the django static files, seconf write 404 and can't see that.

I tried alias too.
Funny things that both servers serves vue fine.
Any suggesions?

Comment: did you check if the user running nginx has read permissions on this directory?

Comment: i gave chmod 755 for directory.

Comment: Check the access log and error log.

Comment: @RichardSmith error log is empty and access jus shown that 404

Comment: did you run `chmod -R 755`, so all files have the same permission? and also `chown -R` for said user, that runs nginx?